# jQuery dynamic layout plugin

Tags: layout, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I've tried both jQuery [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html) and [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) plugins and can't seem to achieve the layout I desire.

Both plugins appear to calculate the "next available space" based on the height of elements on the previous row. For example:

[image: Layout when using Masonry or Isotope plugins]

In this example item #6 goes to the far right because the height of #4 is less than the height of #2 (where I want it to go).

The layout I would like to achieve is more similar to left-floating elements:

[image: What I would like to achieve]

Are there options on the above two plugins to achieve this layout or perhaps a different plugin available?

Answer (score 4):

Two possible solutions

- Try out the experimental [Masonry-ordered script by tasuk](https://github.com/tasuk/masonry-ordered). It has an option to control if you want items to progress left-to-right, rather than Masonry's default next-best space.
- Build your own [custom layout mode for Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html). Your layout mode would be variant of Masonry. Instead of calculating the next best space, it just progresses left-to-right through the available columns.